# Getting Error when Get Pricing of Ethereum

Tags: solidity, price

I am new to Solidity. I took a course from freeCodeCamp. My problem is that I wrote a function whose goal is to get ETH price from ChainLink. However, whenever I work this, it says that execution reverted. I look at some solutions and nothing worked. If you guys help, I really appreciate it.

Code:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {

  mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

  function fund() public payable {
    addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  }

  function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x81fA673678cdd41b29F325d62027BA6492619cb7);
    (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return uint256(answer);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please share your error message to help us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code in this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;

    function fund() public payable {
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        // 0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e -> address of Data Feeds: ETH / USD (Rinkeby Testnet)
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer);
    }

}
```

Remember to inject the smart contract into a Rinkeby Testnet (in this case) to recover the price of ETH.
To see other Data Feeds check this [link](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/).